# findOneandUpdate mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to insert a document only if it does not exist.

The following is my code:

```
export const login = ({ bodymen: { body } }, res, next) =>
    Login.findOneAndUpdate(
      {phoneNumber:body.phoneNumber},
      { $set: {phoneNumber:body.phoneNumber }},
      {new: true, upsert: true }
    )
    .then((login) => login.view(true))
    .then(success(res, 201))
    .catch(next)
```

In my index.js, I have the routes like this

```
router.post('/login', body({ phoneNumber }), login)
```

The problem is that it ends up adding a null value for Phone Number. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried this once without using $set?

Comment: I tried this and it just brings me back a record with a null phoneNumber

Login.findOneAndUpdate(
{phoneNumber:body.phoneNumber},
{phoneNumber:body.phoneNumber},
{new: true, upsert: true })

Comment: This works well, when i hardcode it.

Login.findOneAndUpdate(
{phoneNumber:'1234567890'},
{phoneNumber:'1234567890'},
{new: true, upsert: true })

Comment: Please use some console logs and see what is data returned for `body` & `body.phoneNumber` inside login controller.

Comment: When i do a console.log(body)

I get this:
 { phoneNumber: undefined }

My body in POSTMAN is
{
 "phoneNumber":"1234567894"
}

Comment: At least you now know that the issue is in your code, you have to see why undefined is passed in your code, otherwise, your logic should work fine with a valid phoneNumber.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
Login.findOneAndUpdate(
      {phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber},
      { $set: {phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber }},
      {new: true, upsert: true }
    )
    .then((login) => login.view(true))
    .then(success(res, 201))
    .catch(next)
})
}
```